# What't the best way to automate a WinForms app with command line arguments?

Tags: c#, winforms, automation, command-line-arguments

I have written a small WinForms tool with some textboxes, radiobuttons, checkboxes and a start button. So you enter your input, click on start and there is goes.

Now I want to implement to let the user do some batch processing by allowing command line arguments be passed over.

In the past I would have done it this way:

- parse the command line arguments and fill the textboxes, radiobuttons and checkboxes in the Windows.OnLoad event
- Enable a timer in Form.onLoad event to fire after maybe 100ms
- When the timer fires, disable the timer and let it click on the GUI's start button.

This works, but I'd like to know about more elegant ways of doing this.
How would you solve this?

EDIT:
I want to always show the form as it has a Backgroundworker with a progress bar.

Comment: what is the problem? Why you need timer?

Comment: doesnt sound like a good approach to solve the problem. if you know the input parameters, I would create an xml file with this input sets, and for each inputset, I would execute your business logic (may be a dll) i.e. if you have some sort of seperation in the winforms application via Windows service.

Comment: The traditional way of batch processing does not show a form at all. I would parse the command line and decide whether to launch the form (if no arguments were given), or launch a console/run the batch process silently without a UI.

Comment: Try to think of the command line as *another* user interface, that is independent of the form.

Comment: Thanks Treb, but I want to always show the form as it has a Backgroundworker with a progressbar.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like your function that does the processing reads from the form directly.  It is significantly cleaner to have that function accept all the data as arguments and then when submitting your form, have the data harvested and then passed to the function.

Working this way will enable you to call the function from whatever portion of the program you wish, such as when parsing the arguments passed to the program.

No need for timers, and no need involve the UI at all for the batch.  As Treb mentioned, for batch processing, you may choose to never even show the form (or even UI at all)

Comment: I agree that reading from the form directly is ugly and I can change that easily. But I want to show the form as it shows a nice progressbar. I thought I need a timer to let the onload method finish before the actual work begins. Otherwise onload is finished when all the work is done.

Comment: You can still show the form.  Just stating that you do not have to.  It would probably be better to process the data in a different thread, so neither the argument processing, or the UI have to wait on the other to begin.

Answer (score 1):

If you use UI patterns such as MVP and MVC you can externalize the batch process logic to non UI based classes. If you imagine your console as another UI type then you can build that on top of your existing business logic.

Answer (score 0):

Why is your UI mixed up with your business ? You should have a business part, and a UI part. The UI and the CLI should just act as interfaces to your business.

That is the cleanest way to go.

And concerning your progress bar, just think of a system were you can read a value in % from your business, which would indicate the percentage of work finished. 
Not all that hard